# opening a csv with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting open a csv file with this code and it keeps giving me an "error 52 bad file name or number"

```
 Sub ShowFileDialog()
   Dim x As String
     Dim FF1 As Integer
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With dlgOpen

        .Show
    End With

x = CStr(dlgOpen.SelectedItems(1))
MsgBox x

Open x For Input As #FF1

Do While Not EOF(FF1)

Line Input #FF1, inputdata

Dim lineData() As String
lineData() = Split(inputdata, ",")



Loop
Close #FF1
End Sub
```

The debugger is highlighting the Open for X line but I am feeding it the path name as a string

Comment: You never set FF1 to a file no. `FF1 = FreeFile` before opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line directly before the line causing the error:

```
FF1 = FreeFile
```

Because Open For Input Requires a number between 1 and 512, which should be obtained via a call to [FreeFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264526.aspx).